# How to contain a string to certain values java

Tags: java, string

I need to limit a 3 digit string to accept only 0 and 1 for the first number, 0 to 4 for the second number and 0 to 3 for the third number. Actually I have, after many modifications and new tries the code:

```
public boolean isLocalizacaoValida(String localizacao) {
    String numero1 = localizacao.substring(0);
    int intNumero1 = Integer.parseInt(numero1);
    String numero2 = localizacao.substring(1);
    int intNumero2 = Integer.parseInt(numero2);
    String numero3 = localizacao.substring(2);
    int intNumero3 = Integer.parseInt(numero3);

    if (localizacao.length() != 3) {
        System.out.println("Localização inválida!");
        return false;
    }
    if (localizacao.length() == 3) {

        if ((intNumero1 < 0 && intNumero1 > 1) || (intNumero2 < 0 && intNumero2 > 4) || (intNumero3 < 0 && intNumero3 > 3)) {
            System.out.println("Localização inválida!");
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Localização válida!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Localização inválida!");
    return false;
}
```

With this, it keeps returning true even if the string should be returned as false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substring method that takes a single int will usually return everything from that index to the end of the string. You should use the two parameter version like this:

```
  String numero1 = localizacao.substring(0, 1); //return only the first character
  String numero2 = localizacao.substring(1, 2); //return only the second character
```

and so on.

Secondly, the condition of the if statement to be joined with AND operations. That is, you want to check that the first digit is in a certain range AND the second is in a certain range AND the third is in the correct range. With OR you will get true as long as any one is in the correct range.

```
if ((intNumero1 >= 0 && intNumero1 <= 1) && (intNumero2 >= 0 && intNumero2 <= 4) && (intNumero3 >= 0 && intNumero3 <= 3)) {
        System.out.println("Localização válida!");
        return true;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Localização inválida!");
        return false;
    }
```

See, your condition as written could never be true:

```
 intNumero1 < 0 && intNumero1 > 1
```

requires the value to be less than 0 AND greater than 1? That will always be false.

Comment: I tried that before, and now again, still returning always true

Comment: Yes, like I mentioned in the main post, I tried some different things, I might have gotten lost with my thought process and some things may not make much sense. I tried with the if statement returning true, but I guess my conditions were not correct at the time. Anyway, it's working now! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex,

```
String pattern = "^[01][0-4][0-3]$";
return input.matches(pattern);
```

Comment: What do the `?` characters in your pattern do?

Comment: Changed to better reflect real requirement

Comment: I believe there may be easier ways to get this done, one of them being regex but this is the first phase of a project and we haven't talked about it yet.

Comment: OK, that's correct.  But `{1}` is a waste of perfectly good characters in a regex.

Comment: Sorry, been a long day and I'm trying to type while on the bus. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Substring returns more than one char, try this:

```
public boolean isLocalizacaoValida(String localizacao) {

    if (localizacao.length() != 3) {
        System.out.println("Localização inválida!");
        return false;
    }
    if (localizacao.length() == 3) {
        String numero1 = localizacao.substring(0,1);
        int intNumero1 = Integer.parseInt(numero1);
        String numero2 = localizacao.substring(1,2);
        int intNumero2 = Integer.parseInt(numero2);
        String numero3 = localizacao.substring(2);
        int intNumero3 = Integer.parseInt(numero3);

        if ((intNumero1 < 0 && intNumero1 > 1) || (intNumero2 < 0 && intNumero2 > 4) || (intNumero3 < 0 && intNumero3 > 3)) {
            System.out.println("Localização inválida!");
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Localização válida!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Localização inválida!");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(intNumero1 < 0 && intNumero1 > 1)
```

cannot be right.  It will be true only if a negative number is greater than 1.  And I don't know of any.

You want to use `||`.  That returns true if `intNumero1` is less than 0 **OR** if it is greater than 1.  In other words, if it's anything except 0 or 1.

Comment: Can I suggest something? how about using random number formula rand.nextInt((max+1) - min) + min; to be sure that always the op get zero or one for first number for example? does my solution make sense?

Comment: @KickButtowski If you're thinking about how to test the code, it may make sense.  But the questioner wasn't asking about that.

Comment: could you explain more what you mean by if you are thinking about how to test the code?

Comment: @KickButtowski I thought you were talking about testing.  I couldn't figure out why else you'd want to generate a random number for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(localizacao);
return (num/100 <= 1) && (num%100/10 <= 4) && (num%10 <= 3);
```

You can use `TryParse` instead of `parseInt` if you want to handle the exception.

Comment: Your math is wrong.  If they enter `123`, what will this formula return?